# Update with group by and having

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to update some columns in SQL Server but I have realized there are some `GROUP BY` and `having` conditions. I have used some clues which are written here in some answers but I couldn't fix it up. Can someone help me to find where am I doing wrong in my SQL command please?

Thank you for your answers!

This is what I am trying to do If It would work with GROUP BY.

```
UPDATE T SET T.TES_TARIHI = G.TARIH FROM TESLIM_FORMU T
INNER JOIN GONDERI_HAREKET G ON T.TAKIP_NO = G.TAKIP_NO
INNER JOIN GONDERI_HAREKET G2 ON T.TAKIP_NO = G2.TAKIP_NO
WHERE T.MUSTERI_KODU = 2483 AND YEAR(T.CIKIS_TARIHI) = 2012 AND G.ISLEM_KODU = 15 AND G2.ISLEM_KODU IN (40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,78) AND T.DURUMU = 1 AND T.ISLEM_KODU <> 77
GROUP BY T.TAKIP_NO, T.CIKIS_TARIHI, T.TES_TARIHI
HAVING (DATEDIFF(dd,MAX(G.TARIH), T.TES_TARIHI) >= 1)
```

I changed the code as following:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.TES_TARIHI = X.(MAX(TARIH))
FROM TESLIM_FORMU T
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT TAKIP_NO, ISLEM_KODU, (TARIH)
   FROM GONDERI_HAREKET
   WHERE T.MUSTERI_KODU = 2483
     AND YEAR(T.CIKIS_TARIHI) = 2012
     AND G.ISLEM_KODU = 15
     AND T.DURUMU = 1
     AND T.ISLEM_KODU <> 77
   GROUP BY T.TAKIP_NO,
            T.CIKIS_TARIHI,
            T.TES_TARIHI HAVING (DATEDIFF(dd,MAX(G.TARIH), T.TES_TARIHI) >= 1)) X ON X.TAKIP_NO = T.TAKIP_NO
```

and I get an error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "T.MUSTERI_KODU" could not be bound.

Original code:

```
SELECT T.TAKIP_NO AS 'TAKİP NO',
       T.CIKIS_TARIHI AS 'ÇIKIŞ TARİHİ' ,
       T.TES_TARIHI AS 'TESLİM TARİHİ',
       MAX(G2.TARIH) AS 'GONDERİ HAREKET TESLİM TARİHİ',
       MAX(G.TARIH) AS 'KURYEDE TARİHİ',
       DATEDIFF(dd,MAX(G.TARIH), T.TES_TARIHI) AS 'GÜN'
FROM TESLIM_FORMU T
INNER JOIN GONDERI_HAREKET G ON T.TAKIP_NO = G.TAKIP_NO
INNER JOIN GONDERI_HAREKET G2 ON T.TAKIP_NO = G2.TAKIP_NO
WHERE T.MUSTERI_KODU = 2483
  AND YEAR(T.CIKIS_TARIHI) = 2012
  AND G.ISLEM_KODU = 15
  AND G2.ISLEM_KODU IN (40,
                        41,
                        42,
                        43,
                        44,
                        45,
                        46,
                        47,
                        48,
                        49,
                        78)
  AND T.DURUMU = 1
  AND T.ISLEM_KODU <> 77
GROUP BY T.TAKIP_NO,
         T.CIKIS_TARIHI,
         T.TES_TARIHI HAVING (DATEDIFF(dd,MAX(G.TARIH), T.TES_TARIHI) >= 1)
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,MAX(G.TARIH), T.TES_TARIHI)
```

Comment: You have not completed a join on to TESLIM_FORMU, nor aliased it as T within the subquery, therfore it does not exist in that context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes on Vland answer and its done!

```
UPDATE T
SET T.TES_TARIHI = X.TARIH
FROM TESLIM_FORMU T
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT T.TAKIP_NO, G.ISLEM_KODU, MAX(G.TARIH) AS TARIH
   FROM GONDERI_HAREKET G
   INNER JOIN TESLIM_FORMU T ON T.TAKIP_NO = G.TAKIP_NO
   INNER JOIN GONDERI_HAREKET G2 ON T.TAKIP_NO = G2.TAKIP_NO
   WHERE T.MUSTERI_KODU = 2483
     AND YEAR(T.CIKIS_TARIHI) = 2013
     AND G.ISLEM_KODU = 15
     AND T.DURUMU = 1
     AND T.ISLEM_KODU <> 77
     AND G2.ISLEM_KODU IN (40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,78)
   GROUP BY T.TAKIP_NO,
            T.CIKIS_TARIHI,
            T.TES_TARIHI, 
            G.ISLEM_KODU
HAVING (DATEDIFF(dd,MAX(G.TARIH), T.TES_TARIHI) >= 1)) X ON X.TAKIP_NO = T.TAKIP_NO
```

Thank you for your help and patient Vlad.